# No Emails sent on User Creation in D8 through Rest API

Tags: users, hooks, emails, 8

I'm working in Drupal 8.2.4 currently and building a headless webapp using Rest Web Services module for the endpoints I need.
I'm using the endpoint `/entity/user` to create users, however the default welcome emails are not getting sent out by Drupal when I create the users.

I do have the emails set up to be sent properly and I know this because if I create a user like normal in Drupal with "Notify user of new account" checked, it does send the email. Is there some simple way that I am just missing to get this to work?

I have also tried using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert` using `_user_mail_notify` to trigger the email to be sent, however this is not working either for what I want. My code is as follows:

`/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 * When a new user is created, do things.
 */
function custom_rules_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
  _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $entity);
}`

Am I doing something wrong, is there a simple way to get this to work or does this just not work at all yet in Drupal 8? I will also need to set up Pass Reset emails, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this and it seems like `_user_mail_notify` just isn't working currently in 8.2.4, however I did find a workaround using the `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()` still, but using `hook_mail` and `MailManager` also.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function custom_rules_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
$options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
);
 switch ($key) {

   case 'create_user':
     $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
     $message['subject'] = t('Welcome to the site!', $options);
     $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
     break;
 }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 * When a new user is created, do things.
 */
function custom_rules_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
  global $user;

//  _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $entity);


  $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
  $module = 'custom_rules';
  $key = 'create_user';
  $to = $entity->getEmail();
  $params['message'] = "Welcome to our site! \r\nYour username is " . $entity->getUsername() . " " . "\r\nIf you would like to reset your password, you can at the following link: \r\n" . user_pass_reset_url($entity);
  $langcode = $entity->getPreferredLangcode();
  $send = true;

  $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
  if ($result['result'] !== true) {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
  }

}
```

The way I have this set up works. When a user is created (through drupal GUI or REST API), they are sent a welcome email that also includes a link to reset their password. To do this, you use the `user_pass_reset_url` function that is defined [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/8.2.x). [MailManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Mail!MailManager.php/function/MailManager%3A%3Amail/8.2.x) was pretty simple to use and figure out.

I followed [this](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-send-mail-programmatically-drupal-8) blog to figure out how to do this.